# Unable to Deserialize XML into list

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to deseralize an XML that has a list of objects into a C# object. I've simplified the XML, it's structure looks like this:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("Form")]
public class MyXML
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Employee")]
    public List<Employee> employeeList;
}


public class Employee
{
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Addresses")]
    public List<Addresses> AddressesList { get; set; }
}

public class Addresses
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
}
```

And the XML looks like this:

```
<Form >
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeNumber>6</EmployeeNumber>
    <Addresses>
      <Line1>1123</Line1>
      <Line2>456</Line2>
    </Addresses>
    <Addresses>
      <Line1>567</Line1>
      <Line2>8798</Line2>
    </Addresses>
  </Employee>
</Form>
```

I can successfully serialize the Form/Employee level but the Address list doesn't get deseralized and is empty. Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post how you are trying to deserialize but the following code worked for me to deserialize everything successfully without changing anything in your classes:

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyXML));
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var myXml = (MyXML)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the same deserialization method I'm using. But it's still not generating the list of Addresses objects.

Comment: Actually I see what I did wrong. I was using the incorrect property on [XmlElement("Addresses")]. I was using the name of the class rather than the name of the elements in the XML (in mine they had a different name).

Comment: @user1562497: ah, cool. I was going to ask for the full XML but glad you've found the issue already